Banding function showing 'none' values instead of defined values in Pandas
I'm trying to band years into decades to make visualisation clearer and my function appears to work initially:
def banding(year):
    
    
    if year <= 1989:
        print ('1980s')
        
    elif year <= 1999:
        print ('1990s')
        
    elif year <= 2009:
        print ('2000s')
        
    elif year <= 2019:
        print ('2010s')
        
    else:
        print ('2020s')
        
        
df_clean['decade'] = df_clean['year'].apply(banding)

However, when I check it against the dataframe (df_clean.head()), the column is filled with 'none' on each row instead of 1980s, 1990s etc.
What have I failed to do?
I've tried tolist and to_frame which I have seen used before but neither worked (or I'm getting the code wrong)

Don't use apply, rather go with cut

This could have been avoided by using Pandas' other vectorization operations instead of apply.  As an aside, the reason it returns None is because your banding function only prints using the print function and doesn't specify return.
